# C++ Cannot implement abstract class in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I try to implement the Pattern state in C++, but apparently my base class is `not a class or struct name`. I get this error in Visual Studio 2019. My base class is the following:

```cpp
#pragma once

class LightingState
{
public:
    LightingState() {};
    virtual void shine() = 0;
};
```

The class that should implement the `shine()` function looks like this:

```cpp
#pragma once

class White : public LightingState
{
public:
    void shine();
private:

};
```

For my base class `LightingState`, I have no `.cpp` file, because I do want this class to be a pure abstract class.

When I try to apply the suggested fix (implement pure virtual for Base 'LightingState') I get a warning window:

[image: Error Message]

In the picture, you can also see that my classes are in the same project.

Comment: You aren't including the header where you define `LightingState`

Comment: At the point where the name `LightingState` is used (as the base class of `White`) the name is not visible. The code needs a `#include` directive to pull in the text that defines the class `LightingState`.

Comment: please include the error message as text in the question

Comment: `void shine();` --> `void shine() override;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the compiler is parsing the definition of the `White` class, it doesn't know what the `LightingState` type is, because it hasn't been defined yet. You need to add a `#include "LightingState.h"` statement to `White.h`.

````cpp
#pragma once

#include "LightingState.h" // <-- ADD THIS!

class White : public LightingState
{
public:
    void shine();
private:

};```
````